# Ajax call returning error with xhr.status=200 but not updating?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC 5 project that I'm trying to use Ajax to update a record, re-populate some HTML table data and then return it to the page. My issue is that the Ajax code seems to be dropping down into my error section but it's returning as status code 200 and not updating my page with a partial view. My understanding is that the HTTP code 200 is "OK", meaning no errors. I'm not seeing any errors in the Dev Tools console either.

When I debug the code I can see it going in to the Controller's ActionResult and I'm also seeing data when I step through the partial view's .cshtml page. So, it looks like the data is updating the record and returning the HTML table.

You can see in my Ajax's error section I'm displaying a simple message for status code of 500 otherwise if there is a different error then just display the error code. I plan to clean this up some later but for now I just want to see if any errors.

Anyone know why I would get and status code of 200 yet it drops down into the error section of the Ajax call vs the success section?

```
   function ApproveDeny(homeDirectory, rid, arg, shift, currentEmployeeId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: homeDirectory + "/Exception/ExceptionApproveDeny/",
        data: '{rid: "' + rid + '", arg: "' + arg + '", shift:"' + shift + '", empId:"' + currentEmployeeId + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            $("#exceptionTable").html(response);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            if (xhr.status == 500) {
                alert('Error Code: ' + xhr.status + '\nError: Internal Server Error.');
            }
            else {
                alert('Error Code: ' + xhr.status);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Here is my Controller ActionResult

```
public ActionResult ExceptionApproveDeny(int rid, string arg, string shift, string empId)
        {
            logger.Info("Setting exception Approve/Deny. RID: {0} | Arg: {1} | Shift: {2}.", rid, arg, shift);

            var listExceptions = new List<EssExceptionLog>();
            try
            {
                DAL.ExceptionApproveDeny(rid.ToString(), arg, string.Empty);

                listExceptions = DAL.GetEmployeeExceptionsByDate(CurrentEmployeeId, DateTime.Parse(shift));                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error("Error Approve/Deny exception. RID: {0} Arg: {1} Shift: {2} | {3} | {4} | {5}", rid, arg, shift, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, string.Format("Error: {0} | {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));

            }


            //setup VM with the data needed for the partial view
            var vm = new ExceptionLogDailyViewModel();
            vm.CurrentEmployeeId = empId;
            vm.ShiftDate = DateTime.Parse(shift);
            vm.listExceptions = DAL.GetEmployeeExceptionsByDate(vm.CurrentEmployeeId, vm.ShiftDate);

            return PartialView("_DailyLogExceptionsTable", vm);
        }
```

**UPDATE**

```
function ApproveDeny(homeDirectory, rid, arg, shift, currentEmployeeId) {
    alert("rid: " + rid + "\nArg: " + arg + "\nShift: " + shift + "\nEmpID: " + currentEmployeeId);

    var ajaxData = '{rid: "' + rid + '", arg: "' + arg + '", shift:"' + shift + '", empId:"' + currentEmployeeId + '"}';
    alert(ajaxData);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: homeDirectory + "/Exception/ExceptionApproveDeny/",
        data: '{rid: "' + rid + '", arg: "' + arg + '", shift:"' + shift + '", empId:"' + currentEmployeeId + '"}',
        success: function (response) {
            $("#exceptionTable").html(response);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            if (xhr.status == 500) {
                alert('Error Code: ' + xhr.status + '\nError: Internal Server Error.');
            }
            else {
                alert('Error Code: ' + xhr.status);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

**UPDATE 2**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't try to build JSON by concatenating strings, use `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: You can fall into the `$.ajax` error code if jQuery can't parse the JSON response.

Comment: Check the response in the Network tab of DevTools and make sure it's valid JSON.

Comment: I'll have to look into JSON.stringify(), I'm just going off of an example I've found. I don't see any json in Chrome's dev tools but I'm not an all that versed in using the dev tools so I might be looking at something wrong. I did see another example online and it didn't use any datatype declaration so I tried removing that without any luck. I did some old school alerts in the Ajax to see the data and it looks as though it's correct from what I can see. I'll update my question with new results in just a second.

Comment: Go to the Network tab, perform the AJAX request, click on the URL of the controller, select the Response tab.

Comment: Initially didn't see anything. I had to click the "All" button inside of the Network tab. Still don't see anything under Response, only under Headers. I posted a screen shot in my question.

Comment: It says "Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error". So there's a problem on the server, you need to check its log for the details.

Comment: I did and it basically says the RID is NULL but as you can see it seems to have a value and it is the correct value as well. I'll have to go through it more when I get back to work in the morning. It's not getting to the break point in the beginning of my controller's action result. So, it's like it's never getting to the server.

Comment: Your JSON is not formatted correctly. Property names need to be in double quotes. Use `JSON.stringify()` and you won't have problems like this.

Comment: Thanks, I did look at JSON.stringify and gave that a try but still seemed to have issues. I will use JSON.stringify in the future though.

Comment: Based on the answer you gave, the API doesn't actually want JSON in the first place. When you give an object argument to `$.ajax` it sends URL-encoded format.

Answer (score 0):

After more research and trial and error I finally found the problem. The issue was how I was passing the data to the controller. I also did not need the datatype=JSON. In case someone else is searching for a similar issue, here is the Ajax call I was able to get working.

```
   function ApproveDeny(homeDirectory, rid, arg, shift, empId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: homeDirectory + "/Exception/ExceptionApproveDeny/",
        data: { rid: rid, arg: arg, shift: shift, empId: empId },
        success: function (response) {
            $("#exceptionTable").html(response);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            if (xhr.status == 500) {
                alert('Error Code: ' + xhr.status + '\nError: Internal Server Error.';
            }
            else {
                alert('Error Code: ' + xhr.status);
            }
        }
    });
};
```